# Как указать Gradle положить папку рядом со сборкой?

Tags: java, gradle

3 дня гуглил, и читал документацию Gradle, но так и не нашел реализации задачи.

Имеется программа (на Kotlin), при определенном запросе она должна запустить другую программу, написанную для меня другим человеком(exe фаил).

При сборке не могу понять как указать Gradle чтобы он просто положил папку $someoneDir(в котором и лежит другой exe-шник), например в папку lib моей сборки.

```
task copy(type: Copy){
   from "$buildDir/$someoneDir"
   into "$targetDir"
}
```

Впринципе работает, но жестко привязан к папке $targetDir, которая например при сборке Native или Run меняется. Таким образом я не понимаю как получить текущий конечный каталог сборки, чтоб туда скопировать, либо как указать Gradle данный каталог($someoneDir) как зависимость, чтобы он не просто свалил все файлы из $someoneDir кучей в папку lib(я так уже пробовал), а создал например "lib/$someoneDir". Не обязательно в lib, пусть хоть рядом с exe(в случае с Native) положит.

Comment: много лишнего написано, отсюда непонятно в чем трудность, создайте переменную в ext блоке, которая в зависимости от вида сборки будет менять свое значение

Comment: и под каждый вид сборки прописывать отдельно?

Comment: да, как один из вариантов.. раз сборки разные, вероятно, то и задачи, которые их выполняют также разные, например, можно (не всегда) создать одноименную задачу и добавить в нее вызов метода с параметрами откуда-куда копировать.. или как вариант сделать отдельные таски для каждого копирования и добавить их в граф задач после того как будет создано то, что нужно копировать (тоже не всегда можно, хотя возможности гредла за год выросли), так что способов должно быть несколько для решения подобной задачи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем справилась связка jfx+gradle, в таске jfx `additionalAppResources = "$rootDir/libs"`. Всё что есть в папке libs упадет рядом с папкой `lib` при сборке куда бы не собиралось(будьто Run, Distrib или Zip)